# Why is "never mastered" used instead of "never master"?

Tags: tense-agreement

[Source video at 11:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RtN91vPzt4)

In the anime, the character says:

> That woman, she hates me. She wanted to make sure I **never mastered** genjutsu.

I do not know why **never master** is not used in place of the bold part. It sounds a bit odd to me.

Another great idea to write it as: She wanted I should never master my skills.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52819/discussion-on-question-by-anubhav-singh-why-is-never-mastered-used-instead-of).

Answer (score 1):

> That woman, she hates me. She wanted to make sure I never mastered genjutsu.

Here's a version I think you will like better:

> That woman, she hates me. She wanted to make sure I would never master genjutsu.

(This is similar to "She wants to make sure I will never master genjutsu," but with everything shifted to the past.)

The sentence you took from the audio might sound strange to you, as an English learner, because it is the past subjunctive.  Here's another example:

> I'd rather your boyfriend stopped calling you in the middle of the night.

See, for example: http://www.grammaring.com/past-subjunctive

Comment: Could we have either an explanation of the downvote, or a proposal of a better answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct, albeit with different meanings:

She wanted to make sure I never mastered genjutsu.

and 
 She wants to make sure I never master genjutsu.

As you can see, "she wanted" is in the past, as is "mastered".
"She wants" is current, as is "master".